# Android Media Player Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android

I know what a null pointer exception is i have tried using

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

and

```
 public int check()
  {
if(mp!=null)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 2;
    }

   }
```

doesn't helps. 
  This is the error im getting-

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.openaisearch.www.musicplayer/com.openaisearch.www.musicplayer.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean com.openaisearch.www.musicplayer.Music.check()' on a null
>   object reference

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ArrayList<String> mSongsList = new ArrayList<>() ;
  ArrayList<Long> SongsPath =  new ArrayList<>() ;
  Button btnPlay;
  Music mService;
SeekBar seekBar;
ListView lv;
boolean mBound = false;
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        Music.LocalBinder binder = (Music.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Music.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    startService(intent);

    btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    getAudioList();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mSongsList);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    onSongClick();
    setSeekBar();
    check();
}



@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}


public void getAudioList() {
    String orderBy = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE ;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID }, selection, null, orderBy);

    int count = mCursor.getCount();
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        mSongsList.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));
        SongsPath.add(mCursor.getLong(mCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)));
    }
    mCursor.close();
}

public void onSongClick()
{

   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          mService.playSong(SongsPath.get(position));
           if(btnPlay.getText() == "Play")
           {
               btnPlay.setText("Pause");
           }
       }
   });
}

public void onButtonClick(View view) {
  int a =  mService.stopMusic();
    if(a == 1)
    {
        btnPlay.setText("Play");
    }
    else if (a ==2)
    {
        btnPlay.setText("Pause");
    }
}
 public void check()
 {
     boolean check = mService.check();
 }
public void setSeekBar()
{
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser )
            {
                  mService.setProg(progress*1000);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}


}
```

Service-

```
  public class Music extends Service {

Long b;
MediaPlayer mp;
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
   Music getService() {

        return Music.this;
    }
}

public void playSong(Long a) {
    if (a!= b)
    {   if(mp!=null)
          {
              mp.stop();
              mp.release();
              mp=null;
          }
        b =a;
        Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, a);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), contentUri);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   }


public int stopMusic()
{
    if(mp.isPlaying())
    {
        mp.pause();
        return 1;
    }
    else if (mp!=null)
    {
        mp.start();
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


public void setProg(int a)
{   if(mp!=null)
    {
    mp.seekTo(a);
    }

}

public boolean check()
{
    if(mp!=null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking if the service has been connected to the activity or not using mbound in ur function.

```
           public void check()
              {
                    i f(mBound)
                   {
             boolean check = mService.check();
                   }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting the NPE from this line: `boolean check = mService.check();` So it's `mService` that is null, not `mp`

Comment: i have tired using int instead of Boolean with a return of 1 and 2 still doesn't works

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.openaisearch.www.musicplayer, PID: 1765
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.openaisearch.www.musicplayer/com.openaisearch.www.musicplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.openaisearch.www.musicplayer.Music.check()' on a null object reference

Comment: I can see that from your post... Usually errors come with line numbers next to them, that point to the line of code (or lines of code chain) that caused it

Comment: a specific line number isn't mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I think you trying to bind service that is not started yet. Try to call `startService(intent);` before `bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

Comment: Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE auto starts the service if its not started

Answer (score 0):

Your service class should follow this format; overwrite the `onCreate()` method

you are getting NPE because `mService` is null in line:  `mService.check();`

```
    public class MyService extends Service {
    private Binder binder;  

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        binder = new Binder();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public class Binder extends android.os.Binder {
        public MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;  // return instance
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: even if im using int public int check() { if(mp!=null) { return 1;} else { return 2;} } still it doesn't works

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the service its working for other functions instead of returning a Boolean value i have tried using int to return 1 or 2 still it doesnt works